# Having twice a "location / {}" block in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

For all our sites we have an include file which contains several things, amongst this line:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

For a single site, we do want to redirect all requests from mysite.com/ to mysite.com/blog, as a temporary "fix". The block looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    root        /var/www/mysite;
    include     conf.d/common.conf.inc;

    # Redirect blog
    location / {
        rewrite / /blog redirect;
    }
}
```

This fails however, with the following error:

> Testing nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite:7

**The question**

How can we have a server block with `location / {}` for the `try_files` *and* redirect all requests from `/` to `/blog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try as a solution to make redirect only from exatly root location:

```
 location = / {
        rewrite / /blog redirect;
    }
```

Comment: That works, great!